# How to determine which object this もう少し modifies?

Tags: modification

The もう少し I'm referring to is in the third line of the lyrics of a song called [Don't you see!](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-5138.html):

```
もう少しお互いを知り合うには　時間が欲しい
```

Maybe I haven't learned much about the related grammar, but I'm thinking that the もう少し modifies お互いを知り合う. Therefore I'm translating the line into:

```
It requires time for us to get to know each other a little more.
```

However, I have seen three translations done by different people, and they all translated the line in a way that the もう少し modifies the 時間. So instead of translating the related part as `... get to know each other a little more`, they translated it as `... a little more time ...`

Here are the three translations I saw:

- [Translation 1](http://www.kanzenshuu.com/lyrics/ja-dont_you_see/) (English)
- [Translation 2](http://lang-8.com/24721/journals/279512094081226055591188795203432280966) (English)
- [Translation 3](http://blog.xuite.net/atkins440711/twblog/106079703) (Chinese)

Am I misunderstanding anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with you; this もう少し modifies お互いを知りあう. I checked the rest of the lyrics and [how she sang this](https://youtu.be/Qscyqf0g5Q8). There was no reason to believe this もう少し modifies anything else.

Unsurprisingly, an adverbial phrase tends to modify the closest phrase that follows. 「お互いを知り合うにはもう少し時間が欲しい」 would be the line which should correspond to the translations by others.